# How to insert data into a saved excel file Classic asp

Tags: excel, asp-classic

I have an excel file currently saved on the server.

I'm trying to insert data into the excel file based, I'm new to classic asp and not sure how to do this.

The code below presently downloads an excel file. How would i insert data into the excel file ?

```
 <%

'--declare variables
Dim strAbsFile
Dim strFileExtension
Dim objFSO
Dim objFile
Dim objStream
'-- set absolute file location
strAbsFile = Server.MapPath("WORK.xls")
'-- create FSO object to check if file exists and get properties
Set objFSO = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'-- check to see if the file exists
If objFSO.FileExists(strAbsFile) Then
    Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile(strAbsFile)
    '-- first clear the response, and then set the appropriate headers
    Response.Clear
    '-- the filename you give it will be the one that is shown
    ' to the users by default when they save
    Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & objFile.Name
    Response.AddHeader "Content-Length", objFile.Size
    Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
    Set objStream = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    objStream.Open
    '-- set as binary
    objStream.Type = 1
    Response.CharSet = "UTF-8"
    '-- load into the stream the file
    objStream.LoadFromFile(strAbsFile)

    '-- send the stream in the response
    Response.BinaryWrite(objStream.Read)

   ' InsertSQL = "Insert into [Sheet1$] (3,4) values('test')"
   ' ADOConn.execute InsertSQL 

    objStream.Close
    Set objStream = Nothing
    Set objFile = Nothing
Else 'objFSO.FileExists(strAbsFile)
    Response.Clear
    Response.Write("No such file exists.")
End If
Set objFSO = Nothing
```

%>

Comment: The [link here](http://aspalliance.com/1_Dynamic_Excel_Reports_with_ASP.all) gives a good amount of information on this subject. Remember - Google/Bing are your friends ... for the price of your soul!

Comment: I want to do the exact same thing so I'm wondering if the link from Paul helped you? And/or if you want to share your new/working code?

Comment: I ended up changing the page to asp.net instead of classic